# How does a character changes the domain attuned through the Catalogues of Enlightenment?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The *Catalogues of Enlightenment* (Planar Handbook, p. 166) is a touchstone site whose base ability is:

> **Base Ability:** Choose a cleric domain; you gain the granted power of that domain.

Therefore, a character with the feat *Planar Touchstone* (Planar Handbook, p. 41) or the feat *Touchstone* (from Sandstorm), may forge a link with the *Catalogues of Enlightenment* and choose a cleric domain, gaining its granted power.

There are many cleric domains, though, and therefore a character may wish to switch to another domain.

I have not found any explanation of:

- whether switching the domain is allowed at all,
- whether switching entails attuning another touchstone site and then re-attuning the *Catalogues of Enlightenment*,
- or whether switching is as simple as a *Free Action*<sup>1</sup>.

Is there any rule or guideline for this?

---

<sup>1</sup> *Which, given that some granted powers are reactive in nature, such as the Pride domain's ability to reroll 1s on saves, would seem a tad too powerful.*

Answer (score 3):

The benefit of the feat **Planar Touchstone**, in part, says

> Once you’ve established a link with one planar touchstone site by taking this feat, you may also freely visit other planar touchstones. **When you** do so and **fulfill the higher-order ability’s recharge condition** for the alternate site, **you immediately gain the base ability of the new planar touchstone site and lose the base ability of the previous site.** (Originally *Planar Handbook* 41-2 but last presented on *Magic of Incarnum* 207)

In other words, gaining a connection to a new planar touchstone site severs the connection between the creature and old planar touchstone site. *Regaining* the connection to the old site essentially *resets* the base ability.

As the planar touchstone site Catalogues of Enlightment (*PlH* 66-7) base ability says, "Choose a cleric domain; you gain the granted power of that domain," were a creature to have picked a domain's granted power *via* the Catalogues base ability then gain a new connection (therefore severing its connection with the Catalogues) then *regain* the connection with the Catalogues by satisfying the requirements, the creature could then pick a new domain granted power.

This is, so far as I'm aware, the only method of changing the Catalogues' domain granted power. Ask the DM if there's a way to make this less burdensome if your PC *both* needs to change the Catalogues' granted power *and* lacks ready access to planar travel.

Comment: We always played it such that fulfilling the recharge condition of a currently linked touchstone site allowed one to also re-choose any relevant choices implied or stated in the base ability. However, I believe that is a house-rule, rather than something stated in any of the touchstone ability variants.

Comment: @nijineko Yeah, I think that may be a *perfectly reasonable* house rule, too. I can't find anything *supporting* that house rule, but that may be because my touchstone site notes list the only *other* site that *maybe* offers a choice in the description of its base ability as the Blinding Tower (*PlH* 162)… that, honestly, nobody links to. That makes the only real reason to even *have* that house rule the Catalogues!